# RoR - Obter os strong parameters do controller dentro do Application Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aplicação-web, parâmetros, controller, log

Estou desenvolvendo um processo de logs no meu sistema (Rails 5), mais especificamente dentro do `application controller`. Este processo está sendo criado lá para que eu possa adicionar um `before_save` nos `controllers` que eu queira que gravem logs. Como são vários `controllers`, estou centralizando o método em vez de repetí-lo várias vezes em cada arquivo.
O processo de logs funciona assim: quando o usuário clicar no botão "Salvar", no `form` de edição, o sistema vai buscar no BD o registro atual do objeto que o usuário está editando e comparar estes registros com os campos do `form`. Se os registros forem diferentes, significa que o usuário alterou algum dado. O dado antigo é salvo como log e o novo é gravado no BD. 
Segue abaixo o que tenho até agora:

```
def gerar_log
    @controlr = instance_variable_get("@#{controller_name.singularize}") #objeto que está sendo editado
    nome_cols = @controlr.attribute_names #pega o nome das colunas da tabela do objeto
    ctrl_obj = @controlr.attributes #pega os dados do objeto do BD
    dados_editados = self.strong_params #pega os strong params do controller, que contém o que foi alterado nos campos do form. Estou preso aqui =/
    ...
    ##compara os dados_editados com os dados atuais do objeto e verifica se algo mudou
end
```

O problema que estou tendo neste processo é na hora de pegar os `strong parameters` do `controller`. Como é um método `private`, não dá pra chamar ele diretamente. Tentei criar um método `public`, chamado `strong_params`, que retorna os `params` do método privado, mas ele gera o seguinte erro: `param is missing or the value is empty:`. Se alguém souber de uma solução para isso ou se existe alguma maneira melhor e igualmente dinâmica de fazer este processo que não seja dentro do `application controller`, fico grato se puder me informar.

**EDIT** - Não pretendo utilizar gemas para este processo, pois é algo super simples. O único obstáculo no momento é obter dinamicamente os `strong parameters` de cada `controller`. Se não tiver como fazer dentro do `application_controller`, eu consigo fazer definindo um método dentro de cada `controller` da seguinte maneira:

../controllers/pessoas_controller.erb

```
def log
    @pessoas = Pessoa.find(params[:id]) #busca a pessoa que está sendo editada
    colunas = @pessoas.attribute_names #pega o nome das colunas da tabela pessoa
    parametros = pessoa_params.merge(:id => params[:id]) #pega os dados que estão sendo editados no form e adiciona o ID
    pess = @pessoas.attributes #pega os dados da pessoa do BD
    alteracoes = {}

    colunas.each_index do |i|
    ##compara os dados_editados com os dados atuais do objeto e verifica se algo mudou
    #Se mudou, atualiza a pessoa com os novos dados e salva os dados antigos na tabela de log
      if parametros[colunas[i]].to_s != pess[colunas[i]].to_s 
        alteracoes[colunas[i]] = pess[colunas[i]].to_s unless parametros[colunas[i]].nil?
      end

    end

    @logs = Log.new
    @logs.gera_log(current_user.id, controller_name, params[:id], alteracoes) unless alteracoes.nil? || alteracoes.empty?

  end
```

Para gerar `log` antes do usuário atualizar as informações:

```
before_save :log, only: [:update]
```

O lado bom disso é que faz exatamente o que eu preciso. O lado ruim é que preciso definir este método em cada `controller` que eu quero gerar `log`, e isso vai contra a política `DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)`. Por isso quero saber se tem um jeito de centralizar este método e torná-lo dinâmico para cada controlador, sem usar gemas!

Comment: Você não faz isso no controller, e sim no model. Existe uma gem que faz isso que vc precisa, https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited

Answer (score 1):

A melhor forma que conheço de fazer isso é usando a gem [Paper Trail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail), ela é extremamente dinâmica e eficaz para esse tipo de solução. Utilizo-a bastante em meus projetos para fins de **auditoria**, **versionamento** e **recuperação** de dados.

No caso desta gem os dados serão gravados em banco de dados e não em logs, mas não se preocupe, ela gera suas próprias migrations. Depois basta adicionar um `before_action` em seu `ApplicationController`:

```
class ApplicationController
  before_action :set_paper_trail_whodunnit
end
```

E informar em cada `model` quem será auditado pelo `PaperTrail`:

```
class Widget < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_paper_trail
end
```

Ele é extremamente customizável e poderoso, para isso recomendo a leitura de seu [README](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/blob/master/README.md).

Creio que ela cai como uma luva para sua necessidade.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @LuizCarvalho, mas não pretendo usar gemas para este processo. Atualizei minha pergunta com um método "alternativo" que já está funcionando. Mas o meu desejo é centralizar ele de forma dinâmica.